# Remove all listeners in Firebase java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I know that the documentation says "// In Java, each listener must be removed explicitly.". But there is a problem.

I deploy my app - add a listener (save pointer). But when I re-deploy my app the listener is still there, but I cannot remove it because I don´t have a pointer for it.

So is any way how to remove all listeners? (without server restart)

Comment: There is currently no way to remove all listeners without their handles. We'll think about adding this for a future release of the SDK.

Comment: @Anant is it still the case now - no global remove all listeners?

Comment: whats your issue exactly with leftover listeners?

Comment: Is it still the case now? I just want to shutdown all the listeners once the user logs out in my app.

Answer (score 3):

This still applies until now, as you cannot remove all listeners at once.

To check for any updates you can see this link: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Currently, you can do it inside `onDestroy()`

```
protected void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
yourdatabasereference.removeEventListener(Listenernamehere);
}
```

Comment: What is not working? This will only remove `Listenernamehere`

Comment: I removed the event listener but even after that it listens to data changes

Comment: `onDestroy()` is the last activity lifecycle, which means when it is called the activity will be destroyed.. Im not sure how it is even listening to data changes. if you added the listener inside `onStart()` then removed `onDestroy()`, it means that you left the activity so it wont be listening to any changes..

Comment: @PeterHaddad correct me if Im wrong... But shouldnt the coupling of AddListener & RemoveListener be in onStart & onStop. And same if its onCreate & onDestroy. Similarly onPause & onResume ???

Comment: yes @YoApps it depends where you added the listener but if you add it in `onCreate()` then you remove it in `onDestroy()`